# exporting APK with Proguard fails in real device install

Tags: java, android, proguard

If i export my app in android studio while runProguard=true  and install APK to real device my App stops and says: Unfortunately [yourapp] has stopped.

Whats the problem?
i left proguard-rules.txt file in default status:

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

Without Proguard my app installs and runs perfectly.

Comment: well maybe you are using libraries or java reflection codes that proguard sometimes shrinks away from your code..  check the proguard site for recommended settings for android.. using the -KeepClassmembers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this

```
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
   public <init>(android.content.Context);
   public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
   public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
   public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
   public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
   public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
   static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
   public static <fields>;
}
```